# Ansible - Insert line if not exists and don't insert if line exists that separate by spaces

Tags: ansible

I use lineinfile module to insert a line that doesn't exists but when it's exists with multiple space, it still insert a line.

**Input:**

```
one two three
```

**Expect:**

```
(not exists)     < Insert
one two three    < Don't insert (it's correct)
one  two  three  < Don't insert (having same words but multiple spaces)
```

**My code:**

```
- lineinfile: 
    path: /somefile
    line: 'one two three'
```

**My output:**

```
Before : one  two  three
After  : one  two  three
         one two three
```

Answer (score 1):

Q: *"Expect"*

```
1. (not exists)     < Insert
2. one two three    < Don't insert (it's correct)
3. one  two  three  < Don't insert (having same words but multiple spaces)
```

A: It's not possible to fulfill all the expectations in single run of the module `lineinfile`. It's possible to use [backrefs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/lineinfile_module.html#parameter-backrefs) and preserve the spacing (case 3.). But new lines won't be inserted (case 1.). Without `backrefs` new lines will be added, but the spacing of existing lines won't be preserved (case 2.).

**No backrefs**

The task below does the job. In particular, `regexp` matches any sequences in front, among, and after the words

```yaml
    - lineinfile:
        path: test.txt
        regexp: '^(.*){{ item.0 }}(.*){{ item.1 }}(.*){{ item.2 }}(.*)$'
        line: '{{ item.0 }} {{ item.1 }} {{ item.2 }}'
      loop:
        - ['one','two','three']
        - ['four','five','six']
```

Given the file test.txt

```sh
shell> cat test.txt
one    two      three
```

the playbook with this task gives

```sh
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml

shell> cat test.txt
one two three
four five six
```

As a next example, the `regexp` below gives the same result and restricts the sequence to whitespace only. At least one space must be among the words.

```yaml
    - lineinfile:
        path: test.txt
        regexp: '^(\s*){{ item.0 }}(\s+){{ item.1 }}(\s+){{ item.2 }}(\s*)$'
        line: '{{ item.0 }} {{ item.1 }} {{ item.2 }}'
      loop:
        - ['one','two','three']
        - ['four','five','six']
```

---

**Backrefs**

It's possible to preserve the spacing of the existing lines. See [backrefs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/lineinfile_module.html#parameter-backrefs). But, lines that do not exist won't be added.

```yaml
    - lineinfile:
        backrefs: true
        path: test.txt
        regexp: '^(.*){{ item.0 }}(.*){{ item.1 }}(.*){{ item.2 }}(.*)$'
        line: '{{ item.0 }}\2{{ item.1 }}\3{{ item.2 }}'
      loop:
        - ['one','two','three']
        - ['four','five','six']
```

For example, given the same file

```sh
shell> cat test.txt
one    two      three
```

the playbook with this task skips both iterations and changes nothing

```sh
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml

shell> cat test.txt
one    two      three
```